# Шаблон перегрузки оператора преобразования типа

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Скорее всего глупость спрошу (начинающий, увы), но в гугле ничего не смог найти.

p_Bool - свойство класса типа «bool»

p_String - свойство класса типа «std::string»

```
template <typename T>
operator T()
{
    if (std::is_same<T, bool>::value)
        return p_Bool;
            if (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
        return p_String;
}
```

Компилятор ругается, что не может преобразовать «p_String» в «T» (в коде пытаюсь получить из класса значение типа bool)
Явное преобразование типа конечно можно, но типов может быть не два, а двадцать. На каждый из двадцати типов писать оператора преобразования достаточно долго. Так вообще можно сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same<T, bool>::value)
    return p_Bool;
if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
    return p_String;
```

При этом выбор типа будет проводиться во время компиляции, и если ваш тип — `bool`, то код `return p_String;` как бы не будет рассматриваться компилятором.

Проверка: https://ideone.com/koqMfm

Обратите внимание, что код `static_cast<std::string>(instance)` компилироваться не будет по причинам, изложенным [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18538427/276994), нужно либо использовать `std::string const&`, или вместо оператора конверсии использовать функцию.